# Different user registration

Tags: 7, rules, users, entities

small question

I've created a content type 'Player' with the necessary fields. With the 'Inline Entity Form' module i've added this tot the default user registration form.

Now when a user register, he immediately creates a node for the content type 'Player'. And when he edit his user profile, he also edit the node.

Now I want to have the option, that a user can choose to register as a player or a coach. When a coach register, he should fill in other fields, and so create a node for the content type 'Coach' .

With which modules can I realize this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [Profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) and [Profile2 Registration Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath)

As the project page of Profile2 Registration Path mentions

> Profile2 Registration Path enables you to set a unique registration
>   path for each Profile2 profile type. Users who register via that
>   unique path will be presented with fields from the chosen profile
>   type(s).

Comment: Thx for the answers! 

Extra Question 

With that profile2 module, I Can also use my solution " of creating a node during registration with the 'Inline Entity Form' " ??

Comment: You should be able to do it. There is nothing specific in the module that would stop you from using inline entity forms to do what you are doing.

Comment: I tried , but there seems to be an issue with the integration of Inline entity form in profile2. The field of the entity are correctly loaded in the registration form. But after saving registration, the node is not created, and the values are not saved

Answer (score 0):

You can use [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) and [Profile2 Registration Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module.